# Dudas sobre el manejo de Ajax y Laravel foreach orwhere

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

¿Es correcto añadir al ajax: **var array = JSON.stringify(arreglo)**?

```
$.ajax({
   url:"{{ route('inv_bajas.action') }}",
   method:'GET',
   data:{query:query,array:array},
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#tbody_consulta').html(data.table_data);
   }
  })
```

Asi como si en Controller de Laravel lo estoy guardando bien

```
$array = $request->get('array');

$datosql = json_decode(stripslashes($array));

$data = DB::table('materials');
          foreach($datosql as $d){
$data->orWhere('folio', '!=' , $d);
}

$data->orWhere('marca','LIKE', $query.'%');
               $data->orWhere('descripcion','LIKE', $query.'%');
               $data->orWhere('tipo','LIKE', $query.'%');

               $data->orderBy('folio', 'desc');
               $data->get();
```

Comment: No veo el código que nombras... y ¿hay algo que no funcione?

Comment: Si, es que mando un arreglo y vi que se debe que enviar como JSON.stringify() al AJAX y lo añado en el AJAX dentro de data:{query:query,array:array} y dentro de controller de Laravel lo decodifico con json_decode(stripslashes($array)); y hago un loop foreach($datosql as $d){ $data->orWhere('folio', '!=' , $d);} pero no imprimie la consulta bien no se que estoy haciendo mal